# return true if list of values is not in dataframe column (every single value)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

input data a:

```
obj  number
1    111
2    222
3    333
4    555
```

input data b:

```
obj  number
1    111
2    222
3    333
4    444
```

input data c:

```
obj  number
1    777
2    222
3    333
4    888
```

expected output data:

```
false
true
false
```

tried:

```
~set([111,444]).issubset(set(df_tmp['wahlnummer']))
not set([111,444]).issubset(set(df_tmp['wahlnummer']))
([111,444] not in df_tmp['wahlnummer'])
```

actual output a:

```
-2
-1
-1
```

actual output b:

```
false
true
true
```

actual output c:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

however most of the attemps find patterns where one of the 2 values is not in the dataframe column but not if both are not in. there should be some way for a or operator somehow.

**Only return true if none of the values is in any row of the dataframe**

If i use 111 or 433 not in df then it just thinks all of them don't have the value even if they do have both 1 or none.

**edit2:**
mvce:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'number': [111, 222, 333, 555]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'number': [111, 222, 333, 444]})
df_c = pd.DataFrame({'number': [777, 222, 333, 888]})
print (df_a)
print (df_b)
print (df_c)


print(not(set([111,444]).issubset(set(df_a['number']))))
print(not(set([111,444]).issubset(set(df_b['number']))))
print(not(set([111,444]).issubset(set(df_c['number']))))
```

result of this:

```
True
False
True
```

Comment: Can you add some examples with sample data which not working?

Comment: As @jezrael you might want to add a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: edited my question. @jezrael the first and second temporary-df is identified right but the third one has only 1 of the 2 values in the column so it should not be true. every value of the list should not be in the dataframecolumn before it returns true

Comment: tried to add a mcve =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint):

> Return True if the set has no elements in common with other. Sets are disjoint if and only if their intersection is the empty set.

```
print ((set([111,444]).isdisjoint(set(a['number']))))
False
print ((set([111,444]).isdisjoint(set(b['number']))))
False
print ((set([111,444]).isdisjoint(set(c['number']))))
True
```

Comment: it should only be true if both values are not in any row of the column. so only the last one should be true.

Comment: @J.Doe - are values strings or numeric?

Comment: it is working now =) thank you very much. at the end i was just to confused to test it the right way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing per row of three (3) different dataframes, you can just add the columns in question to one and do the comparison there, creating a new column for your result using `np.where()`.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'obj':[1,2,3,4], 'number':[111,222,333,555]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'obj':[1,2,3,4], 'number':[111,222,333,444]})
>>> df3 = pd.DataFrame({'obj':[1,2,3,4], 'number':[777,222,333,888]})
>>> df1
   obj  number
0    1     111
1    2     222
2    3     333
3    4     555
>>> df2
   obj  number
0    1     111
1    2     222
2    3     333
3    4     444
>>> df3
   obj  number
0    1     777
1    2     222
2    3     333
3    4     888
```

Creating the columns:

```
>>> df1['num from df2'] = df2['number']
>>> df1['num from df3'] = df3['number']
>>> df1
   obj  number  num from df2  num from df3
0    1     111           111           777
1    2     222           222           222
2    3     333           333           333
3    4     555           444           888
```

Now do the comparison using `np.where()`, I believe what you need is true to all to return `True` so we'll use `&`:

```
>>> df1['Conditon Result'] = np.where((df1['number'] == df1['num from df2']) & (df1['number'] == df1['num from df3']), [True], [False])
>>> df1
   obj  number  num from df2  num from df3  Conditon Result
0    1     111           111           777            False
1    2     222           222           222             True
2    3     333           333           333             True
3    4     555           444           888            False
```

Let me know if this helps :)).

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("""obj  number
1    433
2    342
3    111
4    345"""))

values1 = [111, 433]
values2 = [111, 433, 222]

print(all([any(df['number'] == v) for v in values1]))
print(all([any(df['number'] == v) for v in values2])
```

Output:

```
True
False
```